# How to selectively disable IP reassembly?

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-kernel, ip-fragmentation

The diagram below depicts a scenario that involves aggregation of three slow channel throughputs over a `WAN`.
A **fast host** on a `WAN` (@ `54.239.98.8`) is communicating with a host on a `LAN` (@ `192.168.0.100`) which is connected via three slow channels to the `WAN` through three routers running Linux v4.14.151 and `netfilter`/`iptables` firewalls:

[image]

The IP traffic from the **fast host** arrives fragmented and randomized at the three routers (but always from `54.239.98.8`).  I have no control over this fragmentation (corporate politics, go figure)  - I suspect the fragmentation is done on purpose by the fast host.

**THE PROBLEM**:  Each router attempts to reassemble the fragmented IP packets which leads to data loss because the fragments take random paths through the three routers and often one router cannot collect all of the packet fragments for successful reassembly.

Upon analyzing the `iptables / netfilter` diagram below, I can see that the offending reassembly is occurring in the PREROUTING `netfilter` hook, before the rule chains in the `raw` table are processed.

[image]

**THE ATTEMPTED SOLUTION**: I have modified the kernel module `nf_defrag_ipv4` to disable the offending defragmentation in the `PREROUTING` hook as follows:

```
static const struct nf_hook_ops ipv4_defrag_ops[] = {
    {
        .hook       = ipv4_conntrack_defrag, /* I changed this to point to: return NF_ACCEPT; */
        .pf         = NFPROTO_IPV4,
        .hooknum    = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING,
        .priority   = NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK_DEFRAG,
    },
    {
        .hook       = ipv4_conntrack_defrag,
        .pf         = NFPROTO_IPV4,
        .hooknum    = NF_INET_LOCAL_OUT,
        .priority   = NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK_DEFRAG,
    },
};
```

The complete source code of this module can be viewed **[here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.151/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_defrag_ipv4.c#L96)**.

This code alteration disables the reassembly of all incoming packets and allows the unaltered IP fragments to pass to the destination host on the LAN (@ `192.168.0.100`) which accomplishes its own packet reassembly with packets coming from all three routers.  This solution works, but it is ugly, since it modifies the kernel code and disables defragmentation for **ALL** forwarded packets (without regard to their source).

**THE QUESTION**: Is there a better solution then making this code change in the kernel ?
Especially a way to selectively disable IP defragmentation only for packets coming from the fast host on the WAN @ `ip.src == 54.239.98.8`.

Comment: Routers are _not_ supposed to try to reassemble fragments. What you have is backwards. Routers fragment packets that will not fit the next MTU, but only the destination host is supposed to try to reassemble the fragments into the original packet. Fragmentation and reassembly are resource intensive, so routers do not try to reassemble packets. RFC 791, Internet Protocol: "_The basic internet service is datagram oriented and provides for the fragmentation of datagrams at gateways, with reassembly taking place at the destination internet protocol module in the destination host._"

Comment: Also, most companies will block packet fragments at the firewall because of fragmentation attacks. Allowing fragments from outside your network can invite such attacks. The modern solution is to use PMTUD to adjust the MTU of the source host to match the smallest MTU of the path so that fragmentation is unnecessary.

Comment: @RonMaupin Indeed, routers are not supposed to reassemble fragments, but here it's a firewall and connection tracking needs to get whole packets.  But since the traffic is splitted on three links, I doubt any usefull connection tracking can be performed.

Comment: @JeanPierre Me thinks the conntrack still could do full OSI L3 tracking on IP fragmented packets because it can identify and associate these IP fragments by `ip.src`, `ip.dst`, `ip.proto`, `ip.ID`.  Of course L4 tracking would be nearly impossible without reassembly or some store-and-forward-later scheme.

Comment: @Ron Maupin I agree that routers are not supposed to reassemble packets. Are the rules any different for firewalling routers because of their need for L4 connection tracking?

Comment: @Ron Maupin  The "modern solution" of using PMTUD to avoid fragmentation is irrelevant in this scenario because the **fast host**  (@ 54.239.98.8) fragments the IP traffic on purpose so it can scatter it across the 3 slow links...which are aggregated later.

Comment: That is not the way to use fragmentation. In fact, as I suggested above, you should disallow fragments at the firewall. Fragmentation and reassembly end up slowing the traffic quite a bit, anyway. Fragmentation and reassembly are resource intensive tasks that will slow traffic a lot, and splitting traffic on the same flow can cause lost and out-of-order packet delivery that can cause TCP to drop a lot of speed. If this is done on purpose, it is done by someone who does not really understand what is happening.